# Chrome download error from Android Website

Tags: android, google-chrome, download

I clicked on download link on the top right corner from android website itself and chrome shows me the error how to resolve it.
Url:-https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsColors/index.html

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is strange, i had no problem with this download with google-chrome browser.
I suggest you to do a wipe of cache, close browser, re-open it and try downloading  from this URL [SlidingTabsColors](https://developer.android.com/downloads/samples/SlidingTabsColors.zip)

Comment: Thanks it was the cache error i guess but i dont know why:-)